# Can't change 1 arg in controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is my angular code.

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.name = "Name";
});
```

but, when I chaged the paramerter thats not working.

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($para){
    $para.name = "Name";
});
```

How to make it work and can't we use this in our other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses dependency injection based on the given parameter name. It doesn't know `$para`, so it won't get injected. You can however use the array notation where you explicitly say the name of the service to inject. The array notation is also necessary if you minimize your javascript code, so that angular still knows what to inject when your variables get renamed to `a`, `b` etc:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($para){
    // $para is the $scope object
    $para.name = "Name";
}]);
```

If your `$para` is a service, you have to register it so that angular knows what to inject:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .service("$para", function() {
        //
    })
    .controller("ctrl", function($para){
        $para.name = "Name";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope is the binding part between the HTML (view) and the JavaScript (controller). It is a special in angular.

Please read this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp

Answer (score 0):

'$scope' is a special service in AngularJS.
You can, however, create your own service '$para' and inject it if you want.

Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Also, if you don't want to use '$scope', you can use the alternative 'controller as' syntax.
Read about it [here](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/).